# pad with zeros showHex output

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to pad the output of `showHex` with zeros?
for example I want `showHex 11599274 ""` will output `00b0fdaa`.
my naive solution is:

```
take (8-l) ['0','0'..] ++ hex 
    where hex = showHex 11599274 ""
          l = length hex
```

(I know I can do it with `printf "%08x" 5`)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with that. If you are doing it in more than one place then make it a separate function. If you want, you can use Data.Text, which has [left and right justify](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Text.html#g:10). However that would mean packing your String into Text first.

Comment: The definitions of `justify{Left/Right}` are so simple that I would just copy them and change them slightly to work for strings.